# Equation with vectors

Tags: vectors

I would like some help with the following equation:

$$ (\vec{a}\cdot \vec{u})\vec{b}+4\vec{a}=2\vec{u}$$

where $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ are two non-collinear unit vectors, which we know and we want to find $\vec{u}$ . We also know that $(a,b)=\frac{π}{3}$.

Comment: When you write $(a,b) = \frac{\pi}{3}$, do you mean the inner product of the vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$? If that is the case, you can express $\vec{u}$ in terms of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ if you first determine what $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{u}$ is. You can do this by taking the dot product with respect to $\vec{a}$ on both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\vec u=2\vec a+\frac{\vec a\cdot\vec u}{2}\vec b\tag1$$

From $(1)$, we have
$$\vec a\cdot \vec u=2|\vec a|^2+\frac{\vec a\cdot \vec u}{2}\cdot (\vec a\cdot \vec b)=2|\vec a|^2+\frac{\vec a\cdot \vec u}{2}\cdot |\vec a||\vec b|\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$$
Now solve this for $\vec a\cdot\vec u$ using $|\vec a|,|\vec b|$ to get the answer.